# Linux equivalent of dism/sfc?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

What is a bash command that does something very similar to what `dism` and `sfc` do?

I want to know what Linux command I can use to check system file integrity, and automatically repair the system files if corrupted files were found. I guess the command uses hash matching to check the files.

For example, these are the commands I use to check the health of a Windows installation:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:H:\sources\install.wim
sfc /scannow
```

The first command restores the component store (C:\WinSxS) from a mounted Windows installation image, the second command checks system files against corresponding component store files and replace the corrupt files with files from component store.

What Linux Bash command checks system file integrity against a known good Linux installation image and repairs the files if they don't match?

Comment: Whatever mean available would depend on the distribution. So this question tagged only Linux looks too broad. You should specific the (few) Linux distribution(s) you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the package manager.

For example on rpm-based distros:

```
rpm --verify -a;zypper verify;yum check
```

For deb-based:

```
debsums -c
```

For arch-derived:

```
paccheck --md5sum
```