# How to analyze DNS connection failure on dedicated laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, dns

I am connected to a LTE/WIFI router from two laptops. Both laptops are connected via WIFI. The router administration website can be browsed as expected from both laptops. Ping to 8.8.8.8 works fine from both laptops.

- On laptop 1 "external" websites can be browsed as expected.
- On laptop 2 "external" websites **cannot** be browsed. DNS seems to be broken.

## Attempts

1. Manually configuring DNS server at the router (`1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8`).
2. Manually configuring DNS server at the WIFI connection of laptop 2 (`1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8`)

## About laptop 2

- Lenovo ThinkPad T400
- Ubuntu 22.04.3

Any suggestions how to investigate further?

Comment: Perhaps test the disk via `fsck` and system integrity as in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1629242/linux-equivalent-of-dism-sfc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any suggestions how to investigate further?

1. Make sure it is in fact a DNS problem.

   "Websites cannot be browsed" *may* be caused by DNS, but does not necessarily *imply* it's DNS (even if, as the saying goes, "it's always DNS") – for example, you could be unable to browse websites because any HTTP connections fail, but that wouldn't be DNS-related at all.

   Don't immediately believe the error codes that Firefox or Chrome show you. Use other, non-browser tools such as `curl -v https://www.google.com` to check whether the problem is really with resolving the domain name and not with the HTTP or TLS connection.

   One of the most useful tools for investigating any network problem is a packet capture – start Wireshark (or at least tcpdump) on your main network interface and verify what packets you see. (That is, do you see DNS packets at all? Do you see replies? Do you see TCP SYN packets on port 443?)
2. If `curl` seems to work and only the browsers don't, it might be caused by the browsers using *their own* DNS settings, often for DNS-over-HTTPS. Try disabling that feature in the browser and testing again.
3. If it's indeed a problem with domain lookup, check whether you get the same results with tools that bypass the OS name-lookup functions, such as `dig` or `host` or `nslookup` (all of which directly talk DNS regardless of OS configuration). For example, `dig google.com` to directly use whatever's specified in /etc/resolv.conf and `dig google.com @8.8.8.8` to bypass even that.

   (In case /etc/resolv.conf has multiple 'nameserver' entries, test *each* of them separately.)

   Make sure the /etc/resolv.conf file is actually world-readable; you should be able to read its contents and 'dig' and 'nslookup' should work *without* root privileges (sudo), without any permission-related errors.
4. "Whatever is specified in /etc/resolv.conf" might not always be the real DNS server – often it points to a local DNS cache running on the same system, such as dnsmasq or systemd-resolved. If that file contains entries along the lines of 'nameserver 127.0.0.x', use `sudo ss -lp sport 53` to find out what process is listening for DNS queries on that address.

   If you find out that systemd-resolved is in use, check its configuration with `resolvectl` (making sure you don't have any unexpected network interfaces with unexpected DNS servers) and the relevant system logs with `systemctl status -n 200 systemd-resolved`.
5. If `dig` seems to work fine but `curl` still doesn't, check whether the system's name lookup configuration at `/etc/nsswitch.conf` makes sense – the 'hosts:' line specifically. Test the entire facility using `getent hosts google.com` and test the relevant modules ('dns' and 'resolve') one by one using `getent -s dns hosts google.com`.

   (The 'dns' module is the one that directly reads /etc/resolv.conf, while the 'resolve' module is the one that uses the systemd-resolved service. If systemd-resolved is in use, both should work.)
6. On the other hand, if not even tools such as 'dig' work, go back to a packet capture. Make sure the program at least sends out the UDP packets to the server that it's supposedly talking to. (Look also at the MAC address of those packets; make sure it matches your gateway's MAC.)

   If you don't see any packets – check whether you have any unusual interfaces in `ip -c addr`, or unusual policy routing rules in `ip -4 rule` (there should only be three: local/main/default), or unusual firewall rules in `iptables-save` or `nft list ruleset`.

   One common cause is VPN apps (ProtonVPN in particular) installing various "kill switch" configuration to block non-VPN access but failing to remove that configuration when the VPN is uninstalled.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much for all the effort. - Confusingly, I must say: laptop 2 suddenly started to behave as expected without me changing any setting. I might have rebooted it (once again), I can't really tell.